# MVVM nUnit class which uses background worker

Tags: wpf, multithreading, unit-testing, mvvm, nunit

I have the below class I want to unit test:

```
public class MyClass
{
  BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
  ObservableCollection<Product> _data = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

  public MyClass() 
  {
    LoadProducts();
  }

  public ObservableCollection<Product> Data
  {
    get
    {
      return _data;
    }
  }

  void LoadProducts()  
  {
     _worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
     _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
     _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
  }  

  void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
    UpdateData();
  }

  void UpdateData()  
  {
    _data.Clear();
    //Do some work with the retrieved products
  }
}
```

Here is my unit test:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
  _myClass = new MyClass();
}

[Test]
public void Data_Count_Should_Contain_Same_Number_Of_Items_As_Source()
{
  Assert.AreEqual(_myClass.Data.Count, 100, "Data item counts do not match");
}
```

The problem is that once _worker.RunWorkerAsync() is called, the unit test continues and does not wait for the async result so the data is not ready.

I tried adding a **Thread.Sleep** call before the **Assert**, but it looks like that causes worker_RunWorkerCompleted to be called on another thread.  Because of that, when UpdateData is called, I get an exception because a thread other than the thread that created the collection is trying to modify it.

```
"This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."
```

How can I test this code?  Is it possible to do if I cannot change the class itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `ManualResetEvent` to signal the completion of the background work which consumers can hook into

```
public class MyClass
{
  ManualResetEvent _doneEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);
  ...

  public ManualResetEvent BackgroundWorkComplete {
    get { return _doneEvent; }
  }

  void LoadProducts() {
    _doneEvent.Reset();  
    _worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
  }  

  void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    UpdateData();
    _doneEvent.Set();
  }
}
```

Now you can wait on this event from the unit test code.

```
_myClass.BackgroundWorkComplete.WaitOne();
Assert.AreEqual(_myClass.Data.Count, 100, "Data item counts do not match");
```

Comment: Thanks Jared.  I made those changes but there is still one thing I don't understand.  While debugging my unit test, I see that my background worker RunWorkerCompleted is not called back on the same thread that created/started the async call.  I thought that the callback of a background worker happens on the thread that created the bg worker.  As it is now, I get the exception I mentioned at the end of my original post.  Any ideas why the callback is happening on some different, seemingly random thread?

Comment: @Flack this is likely because the `BackgroundWorker` class uses `SynchronizationContext` for it's threading operations. In winforms it will bind calls to the UI thread but in a normal app it will bind it to the thread pool. The best option is to code you're own `SynchronizationContext` specifically for testing purposes. I've had to do this in the past.  See the following for an example  https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/blob/master/EditorUtilsTest/Utils/TestableSynchronizationContext.cs

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Though, I am not 100% sure what to do with class you linked to.  Do you have some sample usage?  I added SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new TestableSynchronizationContext()); to [Setup] and I see Post get called when the async call is run, but then nothing happens.  The unit test just waits at WaitOne().

Comment: @Flack for usages see here https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/blob/master/EditorUtilsTest/AsyncTaggerTest.cs

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Really appreciate it.  It looks like it's working now.  However, I had to make one change in my unit test.  The unit test was reaching the call to WaitOne before _synchronizationContext.Post() was called.  Because of this I had no where to call RunAll().  I added a short Thread.Sleep call before the call to WaitOne() and that ensured that the async call was posted before WaitOne was reached.  Then after the sleep, I can call RunAll(). Looks like I can't guarantee that the async call will be Post'ed before the unit test thread continues.